# Scala Action Map Implementation Issue (follow up)

Tags: scala

This is a fairly long winded question and a follow up to my last one.

I have the following code for an application being built - I am looking to call the function in *handleOne* but it is not working in the action map. I think this is due to the unit assigned to statesVotes in the handler. The goal is to create a menu driven application that performs a set of desired functions. The function in question here is: Get all the state values and display suitably formatted.

Potentially have to make the states into a map but looking for the same functionality of the case class.

```
import scala.io.StdIn.readInt

object myApp3 extends App{

  val dataRE = "([^(]+) \\((\\d+)\\),(.+)".r
  val pVotes = "([^:]+):(\\d+)".r

  case class State(name    : String
                   ,code    : Int
                   ,parties : Array[(String,Int)])

  val states: List[State] =
    util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("filename.txt"))(_.getLines().toList)
      .get  //will throw if read file fails
      .collect{case dataRE(name,code,votes) =>
        State(name.trim
          ,code.toInt
          ,votes.split(",")
            .collect{case pVotes(p,v) => (p,v.toInt)}
        )
      }
    val actionMap = Map[Int, () => Boolean](1 -> handleOne)
    var opt = 0
    do{
      opt = readOption
    } while (menu(opt))
    def readOption: Int = {
      println(
        """|Please select one of the following:
           |  1 - Show All States and Votes
           |  2 - CW Option 2
           |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
      readInt()
    }
    def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
      actionMap.get(option) match {
        case Some(f) => f()
        case None =>
          println("Command not recognized!")
          true
      }
    }
```

// handle one calls function mnuShowStatesVotes, which invokes function statesVotes

```
    def handleOne(): Boolean = {
      mnuShowStatesVotes(statesVotes : List[State])     
      true
    }

def mnuShowStatesVotes(f:() => List[State]) = {
  f() foreach(println())
}

def statesVotes =   states.sortBy(_.name)     //alphabetical order of states
  .foreach{ st =>
      println(st.name)  //show line by split by state name
      st.parties
        .sortBy(-_._2)  //sorts parties by votes in descending order
        .map{case (p,v) => f"\t$p%-12s:$v%9d"}
        .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Essentially want the menu option handleOne to correctly invoke the function in statesVotes.

The text file being used can be found below:

```
Alabama (9),Democratic:849624,Republican:1441170,Libertarian:25176,Others:7312
Alaska (3),Democratic:153778,Republican:189951,Libertarian:8897,Others:6904
Arizona (11),Democratic:1672143,Republican:1661686,Libertarian:51465,Green:1557,Others:475
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your code would benefit by adopting a clear and distinct separation/segregation of roles and responsibilities.

Let's get the preliminaries taken care of.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure, Using}
  
case class State(name    : String
                ,code    : Int
                ,parties : Array[(String,Int)])
```

Now let's parse the input data.

This code has **one** job to do: load the data from the input file. It takes **one** parameter, the input filename, and returns either `Success()` with the accumulated data, or `Failure()` with the error exception.

```
def readFile(filename: String): Try[List[State]] = {
  val dataRE = "([^(]+) \\((\\d+)\\),(.+)".r
  val pVotes = "([^:]+):(\\d+)".r

  Using(io.Source.fromFile(filename)) {
    _.getLines()
     .toList
     .collect{ case dataRE(name, code, votes) =>
       State(name.trim
            ,code.toInt
            ,votes.split(",")
                  .collect{case pVotes(p,v) => (p,v.toInt)})
     }
  }
}
```

Note that `collect()` will simply ignore file data the doesn't fit the expected format. If you were to use `map()` instead then bad input data would cause a `Failure()`.

Now let's put all the output methods, and their descriptions, under one roof. This is most of what the user will see.

```
class Menu(states: List[State]) {
  def apply(key: String): Boolean = {
    val (_, op, continue) = lookup(key)
    op()
    continue
  }
  private val lookup: Map[String,(String,()=>Unit,Boolean)] =
    Map("?"    -> ("show this menu", menu _, true)
       ,"menu" -> ("show this menu", menu _, true)
       ,"all"  -> ("display all voting data", all _, true)
       ,"st"   -> ("vote totals by state", stVotes _, true)
       ,"x"    -> ("exit", done _, false)
       ,"quit" -> ("exit", done _, false)
       ).withDefaultValue(("",unknown _, true))

  private def done(): Unit = println("bye")
  private def unknown(): Unit =
    println("unknown selection ('?' for main menu)")
  private def menu(): Unit =
    lookup.keys.toVector.sorted
          .map(k => s"$k\t: ${lookup(k)._1}")
          .foreach(println)
  private def all(): Unit =
    states.sortBy(_.name)     //alphabetical
          .foreach{ st =>
            println(st.name)  //state name
            st.parties
              .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
              .map{case (p,v) => f"\t$p%-12s:$v%9d"}
              .foreach(println)
          }
  private def stVotes(): Unit =
    states.map(st => (st.name, st.parties.map(_._2).sum))
          .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
          .map{case (state,total) => f"$state%-9s:$total%8d"}
          .foreach(println)
}
```

Notice that only the `apply()` method is public. Everything else is `private` and under wraps.

To create a new data report you just add an entry in the `lookup` Map and add the new method to produce the output.

Now all we need is the code to tie the pieces together and to take user input.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  args.headOption.map(readFile) match {
    case None =>
      println(s"usage: ${this.productPrefix} <data_file>")
    case Some(Failure(exc)) =>
      println(s"Error reading data file: $exc")
    case Some(Success(stateData)) =>
      val menu = new Menu(stateData)
      menu("menu")
      Iterator.continually(menu(io.StdIn.readLine(">> ").toLowerCase))
              .dropWhile(identity)
              .next()
  }
```

Note that `this.productPrefix` is made available if the surrounding object is a `case object`.

Comment: The input data file is specified as an argument on the command line. Invoke the program without any arguments and it will print out a helpful `usage: ...` line that explains what's required.